# Mixing line and scatterplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've looked around a fair bit but I am stumped on this one. **I cannot  find a way to plot a line that is unassociated with a scatterplot.** Here is some of my data and code to clarify the problem. I have data of the following form

```
> head(allData)
  AnnounceDate MarketProbability DealStatus binary BrierScore
1   2000-04-10         0.3333333   Complete      1  0.2340565
2   2000-06-14         0.2142857   Complete      1  0.3618200
3   2000-06-26         0.6846154   Complete      1  0.3690167
4   2000-06-16         0.1875000   Complete      1  0.4364041
5   2000-10-05         0.9555556   Complete      1  0.3078432
6   2000-10-19         0.8500000   Complete      1  0.2670799
```

I would like to create a scatter plot of the `MarketProbabilities` vs. the `AnnounceDate`, and identify whether a `DealStatus` is `Completed` or `Terminated` using colour.

```
(ggplot(data=allData, aes(x=AnnounceDate, y=MarketProbability, colour=DealStatus))
 + geom_point() + scale_colour_hue(h = c(180,0)))
```

[image]

I would also like to overlay a rolling Brier score, I have tried

```
(ggplot(data=allData, aes(x=AnnounceDate, y=MarketProbability, colour=DealStatus))
 + geom_point() + scale_colour_hue(h=c(180,0))
 + geom_line(aes(x=AnnounceDate, y=BrierScore)))
```

[image]

I am confused why two coloured lines are plotted? How do I dissociate the line with the previous plotted data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @MattBagg has pointed out, this issue is fixed by moving the `aes()` for colour out of the main `ggplot()` call and into the `geom_point()` call.

```
library(ggplot2)

allData = read.table(header=TRUE,
colClasses=c("Date", "numeric", "character", "numeric", "numeric"),
text="AnnounceDate MarketProbability DealStatus binary BrierScore
2000-04-10         0.3333333   Complete      1  0.2340565
2000-06-14         0.2142857   Complete      1  0.3618200
2000-06-26         0.6846154   Complete      1  0.3690167
2000-06-16         0.1875000   Complete      1  0.4364041
2000-10-05         0.9555556   Complete      1  0.3078432
2000-10-19         0.8500000   Complete      1  0.2670799")

p1 = ggplot(data=allData, aes(x=AnnounceDate)) +
     geom_point(aes(y=MarketProbability, colour=DealStatus)) + 
     scale_colour_hue(h = c(180,0)) + 
     geom_line(aes(y=BrierScore))

ggsave(filename="plot_1.png", plot=p1, height=2.5, width=5)
```

[image]

Comment: geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret your comment: Using ggplot2 0.9.2.1, the posted code runs without without error, and outputs the posted png. As far as I can see there is no need to define the group aesthetic.

Comment: I have the same version. really amazing!os issue?

Answer (score 5):

The aes() in ggplot() are inherited by the subsequent geoms.  You assigned colour=DealStatus, which gets inherited by geom_line() and it needs to make two lines to make two colors.  I can't test this because I am on my phone, but try moving the colour assignment out of the main ggplot and into the geom_point():

```
ggplot(data = allData, aes(x=AnnounceDate)) +
     geom_point(aes(colour=DealStatus, y=MarketProbability)) + 
     scale_colour_hue(h = c(180,0)) +
     geom_line(aes(y=BrierScore, group=1))
```

I am adding a constant as a group argument to tell it to connect all the points.  Otherwise, ggplot sometimes makes the wrong guesses.